# Find Property value in a nested object using PropertyInfo & Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

here is a sample of a code that let me get the value using an object's property name, it works with flatten objects.

```cs
        public static object GetPropValue<T>(T obj, String propName)
        {
           if (obj == null) { return null; }

           Type type = typeof(T);
           PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(propName);
           if (info == null) { return null; }

           return info.GetValue(obj);
        }
```

How can I make this work if T happens to be a nested object?
Here is my attempt so far with recursive but no luck yet.

```cs
        public static object GetPropValue<T>(T obj, String propName)
        {
           if (obj == null) { return null; }

           Type type = typeof(T);

           foreach(PropertyInfo property in  type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public))
           {
              if(!property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
              {
                 var nestedObj = (from subObj in obj select property.GetValue(subOjb));

                 //recursive call where object pass in is
                 //one of the nested property object.
                 GetPropValue(nestedObj, propName);

              }
              else
              {
                 return property.GetValue(obj);
              }
           }

        }
```

In this case, for example a nested object can be:

```
    public class A{
       public string property1 {get; set;}
       public B property2 {get;set;}
    }

    public class B{
       public string property3 {get;set;
       public C property4 {get;set;}
    }

    public class C{
       public string property5 {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `if T happens to be a nested object`?

Comment: sure, I updated an example in the question, but keep in mind I don't know what type of object this is at run time, hence the use of generic type.

Comment: Thanks Heretic, but I think the solution in that question either assume we know before hand how many level of nested object.  Or they rely on having the dot notation in the name to predetermine the nested level.  In my case it won't work because I only have the property name without the dot notation.

Comment: Can you show your usage along with the bad output and what you want it to be...

Comment: On Stack Overflow, a question does not have to be _exactly_ the same as your scenario for it to be a duplicate, especially when, as is the case here, the proposed duplicate has a large variety of different answers, at least one of which can easily be adapted to your needs. Note that the only real difference between your question and the marked duplicate is that you have a poorly-defined problem, i.e. it's not clear what is supposed to happen if a property with a given name is present in two or more levels of property indirection. ...

Comment: ... But, assuming you just want to return the first one found, you can use any one of several of the answers on the marked duplicate, simply ignoring the calls to `string.Split()` and the subsequent parsing of the property path...just always use the property name given, and return as soon as you find it.

Comment: Note that if you want to respond to someone, the best way is to put @ in front of their names. I didn't receive a notification of your comment; I just happened to come back to this question when I was reviewing my history.